# Match formula in vba array macro for excel data

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

```
  Dim rng As Range
Lastrow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
With Sheets("sample")
    Set rng = .Range(.Range("AM1000000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0), .Range("AM" & Lastrow))
End With
rng.FormulaArray = "=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(1," & Chr(10) & "  (order!R2C17:R1000000C17=RC[-22])*" & Chr(10) & "  (order!R2C7:R1000000C7=RC[-32])*" & Chr(10) & "  (order!R2C24:R1000000C24=RC[-15])," & Chr(10) & "  0)), ""pass"",""review"")"
rng = rng.Value
```

I have VBA code to populate a field to compare two worksheets and return the result. However, this code is giving me only result for first line. Is there any way to make this array works for every line?

Thanks!

Comment: @YowE3K I think that the column `AM` is yet to be filled while other data exists in the `Sheets("sample")` (the Q being a follow-up on a previous answer of mine). Yet I leave the confirmation to OP.

Comment: @A.S.H - If an array formula can't be populated in multiple cells at a single time, your answer is probably the solution, so I removed my comment just as you were replying to me :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set each cell's formula alone, because the formula you are using is an array formula for a single cell. Try it this way:

```
With rng
  .Cells(1).FormulaArray = "=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(1," & Chr(10) & _
                           "  (order!R2C17:R1000000C17=RC[-22])*" & Chr(10) & _
                           "  (order!R2C7:R1000000C7=RC[-32])*" & Chr(10) & _
                           "  (order!R2C24:R1000000C24=RC[-15])," & Chr(10) & _
                           "  0)), ""pass"",""review"")"
  .Filldown
  .Value = .Value2
End With
```

Comment: @YowE3K Feel free! I trust your edits so no need to ask me anytime :) I didn't much care about editing the formula itself.

Comment: Thanks - it gets rid of that annoying scroll bar!

Comment: It saying "Object variable or With block variable not set" is there any way to fix this?

Comment: @terny my code should replace the very last two lines of your OP's code. Is that what you did? Because you still need to `set` the range first.